# grep warning: recursive directory loop

Tags: grep

I'm searching recursively some location e.g. `/cygdrive/c/dev/maindir/dir/`
There's a loop inside that directory structure i.e. there's a link `.../maindir/dir/loopedDir/loopedDir` pointing to `.../maindir/dir/loopedDir`.

When I run:

```
grep --exclude="/cygdrive/c/dev/maindir/dir/loopedDir/loopedDir" 'myPattern' -R /cygdrive/c/dev/maindir/dir/
```

...it works fine, like expected and finds what I need.
However, I also get a warning:

```
grep: warning: /cygdrive/c/dev/maindir/dir/loopedDir/loopedDir: recursive directory loop
```

...and I'm wondering why is that. Shouldn't dir exclusion prevent this particular looping occurance? How should I modify my query in order not to get the warning?

Comment: Try `--exclude-dir="/cygdrive/c/dev/maindir/dir/loopedDir/loopedDir"` which says to *exclude directories from recursive searches*.

Comment: The argument to `--exclude` is a pattern that is matched against the directory name I believe. Try `--exclude=loopedDir`.

Comment: `grep` is the UNIX tool to **G**lobally search for **R**egular **E**xpressions and **P**rint (i.e. **GREP**) the result. Forget you ever heard of it's options to recursively find files, those were a terrible idea completely contrary to the UNIX way of doing things and should never have been implemented. The UNIX tool to **FIND** files is aptly named `find`.

Answer (score 8):

Add grep's option `-s` to suppress this and other error messages.

Comment: The warning message is not the thing that bothers me - the reasons behind the message are. I'm not trying to get rid of the message, but rather of what causes it - I want to understand why it works this way.
Still, useful hint, thx.